# Why web3j wallet address is different than hardhat network address which receives tokens

Tags: wallets, addresses, web3j

I am just playing with web3j and hardhat

I use web3j to generate wallet . This wallet has some address - let's call it A

When I'm testing and I receive token in hardhat and check with getTransaction the address in to field is different from web3j wallet address .

why ?

I expect "to" field to be the same as my wallet address